# how to display uploaded image on a website without saving it in a database using php

Tags: php, database, image

I'm working in a content based image retrieval php project.The user should upload an image to retrieve images similar to it . I need to display the query image without saving it in database. I tried two different ways to do that but it didn't work. The image appear as image icon.

```
        $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];

        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, $fileSize);
        $content = addslashes($content);
```

I tried this:

```
   echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $content ) . '"  height=200 width=200 />';
```

and this:

```
   header("content-type: image/jpeg");
   echo $content;
```

Comment: What's `$row['image']`? How are you saving the images, if they're not in a database? There's nowhere near enough context here to be able to answer this.

Comment: sorry I copied this from a different code without changing  i will change it

Comment: Thanks for updating the code, but it doesn't help too much - what's `$fp`? Are you reading the content of your image file into `$content`? In which case, you almost certainly don't need to call `addslashes()` on it.

Comment: $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];

$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');

Comment: Yeah, your second example ought to work, I think, if you just echo out `$content` _without_ the `addslashes()`.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [this jquery plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). See Documentation section and it's a PHP implementation example. Basically, the plugin upload the image, save temporally on server file system and then send back so client to be rendered. Once it's on your file system you can do whatever you want with it (make the query, delete it for example). I think it's a good aproach, it was to me!!.
Hope This Helps!!